# Make Link HIdden in PHP on certain database queue

Tags: php, html

Im trying to make an entire NAV link disappear if the user has paid but I can only get the text to disappear I get errors.

Here is my code:

```
 <li> <a class="  " href="paynow.php" aria-expanded="false">
                    <span class="hide-menu"> <?php echo $unlockcourse ?></span></a>

                    </li>
```

Php code:

```
 $haspaid = ($userinfo['id_haspaid']) * 1;
    $unlockcourse="";
        if($haspaid==0){
            $unlockcourse="- Unlock Full Course";
        }else if($haspaid==1)
            $unlockcourse="";
        {
        }
```

I want the entire section to be hidden, right now the text is hidden so I can still click an invisible link

Comment: You could simply include the whole nav link in variable, or use some display:none class and modify class by additional variable from php.

Comment: Make `$unlockcourse` a boolean. If it's true, render the whole HTML block from `<li>` to `</li>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code.

PHP:

```
$haspaid = ($userinfo['id_haspaid']) * 1;
$unlockcourse = true;
if($haspaid == 0){
    $unlockcourse = true;
} else if ($haspaid == 1) {
    $unlockcourse = false;   
}
```

HTML:

```
<?php if ($unlockcourse == true) { ?>
    <li>
        <a href="paynow.php" aria-expanded="false">
            <span class="hide-menu">-Unlock Full Course</span>
        </a>
    </li>
<?php } ?>
```